# Instalação do Swift no Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: swift, ubuntu

Estou com dificuldade na instalação. Seguindo um tutorial, fiz todos os procedimentos mas quando digito para compilar o comando `./swift` ele apresenta um erro que está na imagem.

[image: Erro ao compilar Swift no Ubuntu]

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Copia o erro e cola aqui, imagens podem até ajudar, mas não trabalhamos com OCR, para facilitar poste "TEXTO", pode deixar a imagem.

Comment: votei por deixar aberta, pois o Swift é uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento e isto esta obviamente dentro do contexto do escopo e notem também que muitas perguntas sobre configuração e ou instalação de IDEs, compiladores e SDKs são bem aceitas pela comunidade, leiam: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic